# Why is the code returning a TypeError - Python

Tags: python, csv, flask

```
@app.route("/admin/3")
def admin3_p():
    return render_template("input_test.html")


@app.route("/admin/3", methods=['POST'])
def student_name():
    with app.test_request_context('/admin/3', data='student'):
        variable = request.form.get('student', list(''))
        return variable


# Connect to CSV
def csv_func():

    variable = student_name()

    csv_f = "names.csv"
    titles = ["Event", "Student", "Grade"]
    students = [["Ev", "St", "Gr"], [variable]]

    with open(csv_f, 'w') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerow(titles)
        csvwriter.writerows(students)

    with open(csv_f, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        titles = next(csvreader)

        for student in csvreader:
            students.append(students)

    print('Fields: ' + ', '.join(title for title in titles))

    print(students)


csv_func()
```

I am trying to make a website with Flask. Th csv_func method is supposed to take the input from the html and print it to a csv file.
It returns "TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list" When it runs

Comment: why do you have @app.route("/admin/3", methods=['POST'])  decorator with student name? You should permorm model and csv changes from controller, not wise versa

Answer (score 1):

Technically the error is because function with a route decorator is considered 'a view' and is supposed to return a page, yet yours student_name returns a tuple (of student names)

Yet I have to tell you that you got it wrong idea of web app syntax and structure. Your flow of control is opposite from what is should be. You should initiate model and csv changes from controller (student_name function), and you are doing it vise versa, by calling student_name from . The main code usually just start web app with something like

`app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81)`

So you should restructure you code in a so student_name function invokes csv changing function.

I guess you think that web app form is akin to input command in python, yet a web app is very different from python console input. The main difference is that website normally offer several different pages, and user is free to land on any page he likes. So normal webserver just wait for user landing to one or another page or sending one or another form. Thus the structure of web app is a set of pages, routes and controllers for that pages, and main code just starts the flask server. Go throw some introductory flask tutorial if it is still
unclear. E.g. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Most web apps follow UI design pattern called Model-View-Controller, where user actions, such as opening a webpage on a specific web address or filling a form first hit some controlling code, which the  initiates some changes in the model (data). [image]

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `app.route(...)` decorator above `def student_name():`.